# Windows Forms, Syntax error in SendMessage line

Tags: c#, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I am using Windows Forms and I am attempting to use SendMessage to get the ComboBox dropdown rectangle. However I can't seem to find the correct parameter combination that will allow the code to compile.

I have tried copying examples I found, but nothing seems to compile.

Here are some examples of lines that do not compile:

```
var z1 = SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);  // The best overloaded match has some invalid arguments.

var z2 = SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0152, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0); 

var z3 = SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT, 1, 0); 

var z4 = SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0152, 1, 0);
```

Thanks in advance to anyone who has any ideas to make this work.

Here is my complete code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(
          int hWnd,      // handle to destination window
          uint Msg,       // message
          long wParam,  // first message parameter
          long lParam   // second message parameter
          );

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<string> itms = new List<string>();
        itms.Add("Choice 1");
        itms.Add("Choice 2");
        itms.Add("Choice 3");
        itms.Add("Choice 4");
        itms.Add("Choice 5");

        this.comboBox1.Items.AddRange(itms.ToArray());
    }

    private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        const int CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT = 0x0152;
        IntPtr hWnd = comboBox1.Handle;

        var z = SendMessage(hWnd, CB_GETDROPPEDCONTROLRECT, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0);  // The best overloaded match has some invalid arguments.

        var z1 = SendMessage(hWnd, 0x0152, (IntPtr)1, (IntPtr)0); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You declared `wParam` and `lParam` as `long`, so why do you try to pass `IntPtr`s instead? But I guess you need a different overload of `SendMessage` that takes `IntPtr` or even `ref IntPtr` for `lParam` ot receive the result.

Comment: Also &H14F would be 0x14F - &H is VB.Net notation for a hex literal. (Its better defined as a named const)

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html

Comment: @AlexK. &H14F was a cut and paste mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the dropdown rectangle of a combobox you can do this:

First, declare the [`RECT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//dd162897(v=vs.85)) struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;
    public int Top;
    public int Right;
    public int Bottom;
}
```

Note: the Microsoft documentation states these fields should be `long`, but I tested it and for some strange reason `SendMessage` answers with `int`'s here.

Second, the correct `SendMessage` declaration: For this special case you can now use a `ref RECT` parameter. Note that in your versions there are mistakes: `hWnd` needs to be an `IntPtr` while `wParam` is only `int` and not `long`:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(
    IntPtr hWnd,    // handle to destination window (combobox in this case)
    int Msg,    // message
    int wParam, // first message parameter
    ref RECT lParam  // second message parameter
);
```

Third, the usage:

```
RECT rect = default;
int result = SendMessage(comboBox1.Handle, 0x0152, 1, ref rect);
```

Where `comboBox1` is of course your ComboBox. If `result` is zero, the call failed, otherwise it succeeded and `rect` should contain the desired values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out. Stand by.